# How to use read_msgpack with a Dataframe child class

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I have is a class that inherits from DataFrame, but overrides some behavior for business logic reasons. All is well and good, but I need the ability to import and export them. msgpack appears to be a good choice, but doesn't actually work. (Using the standard msgpack library doesn't even work on regular Dataframes, and the advice there is to use the dataframe msgpack functions.)

```
    class DataFrameWrap(pandas.DataFrame):
        pass
    df = DataFrameWrap()
    packed_df = df.to_msgpack()
    pandas.read_msgpack(packed_df)
```

This results in the error

```
File "C:\Users\REDACTED\PROJECT_NAME\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\packers.py", line 627, in decode
return globals()[obj[u'klass']](BlockManager(blocks, axes))
KeyError: u'DataFrameWrap'
```

when it reaches the read_msgpack() line. This works if I replace the DataFrameWrap() with a regular DataFrame().

Is there a way to tell pandas where to find the DataFrameWrap class? From reading the code, it looks like if I could inject {"DataFrameWrap": DataFrameWrap} into the globals as seen from this file, it would work, but I'm not sure how to actually do that. There also might be a proper way to do this, but it's not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. As usual, it was much less complicated than I assumed:

```
    from pandas.io import packers
    class DataFrameWrap(pandas.DataFrame):
        pass
    packers.DataFrameWrap = DataFrameWrap

    df = DataFrameWrap()
    packed_df = df.to_msgpack()
    pandas.read_msgpack(packed_df)
```